# How to add checkmarks when using tableview and a searchbar

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a searchbar which filters my array. What I have tried to do in a couple of days is to add a checkmark when I tap the cell. I know how to add checkmark, but I don't know how I would make the checkmark stay at the same cell when I search and when I don't.

Right now I am trying to make an array which shows all checked rows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if schouldShowSearchResults{
        if checkedArrray.contains(filteredData[indexPath.row]){
            checkedArrray.remove(at: checkedArrray.index(of: filteredData[indexPath.row])!)
        }else{
            checkedArrray.append(filteredData[indexPath.row])
        }
    }else{
        if checkedArrray.contains(array[indexPath.row]){
            checkedArrray.remove(at: checkedArrray.index(of: array[indexPath.row])!)
        }else{
            checkedArrray.append(array[indexPath.row])
        }
    }

    print(schouldShowSearchResults)
    print(checkedArrray)
}
```

CellforRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = serialNumberTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serialNumbers") as! SerialNumberCell

    if schouldShowSearchResults{
        cell.serialNumberLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        cell.serialNumberLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

So what I wonder now is how I would add a checkmark to all cells which has same text value as my checkedArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a separate array to track checkmarks, add a `Bool` field to your data model. This way the status of whether a row should be checked or not is tied to your data model, not a separate array.

This makes it much simpler to deal with filtering and sorting your table view data without trying to keep other separate data in sync.

Then in your `didSelectRowAt` method you should get the data model for the given indexPath, toggle its `selected` (or `checked`) property, and then tell the table view to reload that one indexPath. This makes the code in your `didSelectRowAt` much, much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: What do you mean by "Bool field"?

Comment: A property with a type of `Bool`. Surely your main array of data is some sort of struct or class, right? Add a `Bool` property to track that data's "checked" state.

Comment: I dont understand. Do you want me to make a dictionary like this? var dict = [["checked": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]], ["unchecked": ["tset1", "tset2", "tset3"]]]

Comment: I made my main array like this var array = ["43598fdsffgdi", "3459jhgdkfhg", "oidfgho45986", "bvfdht2345", "dfgnkd4224", "dhkghkrdhg435", "fgkhjlgfjh3456", "fgjfg43", "nndjwt31"]

Comment: Not at all. As it turns out (based on your posting of `cellForRowAt`), your data model is just an array of `String`. What you really need is an array of `struct`. This struct should have all of the data you need for each row. At the moment that appears to be just the title (your current string) and now a `Bool` to keep track of whether the data is selected or not. By doing this you have one array (really two - original and filtered) instead of a separate array for the strings and checkmarks. This will make all of your code cleaner and it will be easier to add additional data when needed.

Comment: Okey, I dont have so good experiece in swift. I need to read about structs and try out your method:)

Comment: So I have read about array of structs. I cant see how this could be a solution to my problem. If there is anything you dont understand with my question, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` at the bottom of your `didSelect` method.

Then, in the `cellForRow` method, which is called every time you reload the table, you simply look to see if that cell's text value is equal to the checkedArray that you want (i.e. if it should show a checkmark)

Finally, your cells can have a checkmark in the form of `UIImageView` that is toggled between `isHidden` true or false if the text value is equal or not, as mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, but how would i check if the cells text is equal to checkedArray?

Comment: Could you post your cellForRow

Comment: I dont want to use UIImageView. I want to use the cell.accesoryType = checked.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days of research i found out that using array of structs is the best. I made two arrays, one filtered and one normal.

```
struct filtered{
    var text_filtered: String
    var isChecked_filtered: Bool = false
}

struct normal{
    var text: String
    var isChecked: Bool = false

}
```

In my didSelectRowAt function i did like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

                if schouldShowSearchResults{
                    if filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].isChecked == false{
                        filtered

                    filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].isChecked = true
                    let indexOfArray = array.index { $0.text == filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].text_filtered}
                    array[indexOfArray!].isChecked = true
                    print(filteredDataArray[indexPath.row])
                }else{
                    filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].isChecked = false
                    let indexOfArray = array.index { $0.text == filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].text_filtered}
                    array[indexOfArray!].isChecked = false
                    print(filteredDataArray[indexPath.row])
                }


            }else{
                if array[indexPath.row].isChecked == false{
                    array[indexPath.row].isChecked = true

                    print(array[indexPath.row])
                }else{
                    array[indexPath.row].isChecked = false
                    print(array[indexPath.row])
                }


            }

            tableView.reloadData()

            }
```

After this I also stumbled over a problem. It turned out my cells were reusable, so every time I scrolled in my tableView my checkmarks were reordered. I solved this by doing like this in cellForRowAt:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultCell") as! customCellClass

    if schouldShowSearchResults{
    cell.accessoryType = filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.stringLabel.text = filteredDataArray[indexPath.row].text_filtered
    }else{
    cell.accessoryType = array[indexPath.row].isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.stringLabel.text = array[indexPath.row].text
    }
    return cell
```